Sorting References by entry type numerically
biblatex experts
I'm using biblatex for my references. I have designed my bibliographic entries such that the entry keys are pure positive integers, that is, without alphabetic characters. I would then like to sort my bibliography NUMERICALLY according to their entry keys.
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting=sortbyentrykey]{biblatex}

%i have 3 bib files located in the same folder as this file
\addbibresource{4.bib}
\addbibresource{256.bib}
\addbibresource{10000.bib}

%the contents of "4.bib" are
%@book{4,
%author={Author Four},
%title={Title Four},
%publisher={Publisher Four},
%}

%the contents of "256.bib" are
%@book{256,
%author={Author TwoFiveSix},
%title={Title TwoFiveSix},
%publisher={Publisher TwoFiveSix},
%}

%the contents of "10000.bib" are
%@book{10000,
%author={Author TenThousand},
%title={Title TenThousand},
%publisher={Publisher TenThousand},
%}


%i defined a sorting template that will sort according to entry key
\DeclareSortingTemplate{sortbyentrykey}{\sort{\field{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{4}
\nocite{256}
\nocite{10000}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Upon compiling (pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX), the bibliography was sorted as follows:
number 1: reference "10000"
number 2: reference "256"
number 3: reference "4"
I expected this result since biblatex apparently sorted the entry keys by treating them as strings, thus, 1 comes before 2, and 2 comes before 4. Therefore, 10000 comes first ("1"), then 256 ("2"), and finally, 4.
What I would desire is for the references to be sorted such that 4 comes first, then 256, then 10000, that is, they were sorted "numerically".
Kindly seeking your help. Thank you.
Dennis

%i have 3 bib files located in the same folder as this file
(newline)
\addbibresource{4.bib}
\addbibresource{256.bib}
\addbibresource{10000.bib}

I guess you are looking for the style=numeric option to have cites numbered by the order they appear in text. This can be done without using numeric keys, which in IMHO, is not a good idea.  See  here for other styles.

hi Fran, your solution is also useful in cases where my citation order happens to be the same as the ordering of the entry keys. but this rarely happens ;) thank you, anyways ;) thank you, too, for the link on bibliographic styles. i'm being reminded to study carefully again the biblatex manual on how to make my own bibliographic styles, either building on existing ones (relatively easier), or by making something completely different. (relatively difficult) ;)

I would use the  free JabRef to make the keys automatically and consistently, and with all the references in the same file, except if you to maintain different references databases to some reason unrelated with the document (but never single  references per file, I hope that this was only  for example purposes).

hi Fran, the idea of automatic and consistent generation of keys was something i tried before, but for some reason, i found it more difficult in the long run, thus i opted to use manual assignment of keys ;) also, i have this recurring "memory" issue with my laptop, thus i also opted for single references per file, and everything went well so far.

references in a single file would be highly ideal, though, if not for the memory issues, and risk of putting all your eggs in one basket, so to speak, and losing all of them when the basket is damaged ;) (there were instances when i almost lost all my references in the single file, when that single file was corrupted). though JabRef is a new idea for me. i will research more about it. thank you, friend ;)

Add a padding at the left, so that all numbers have the same width:
\begin{filecontents}{numbered.bib}
@book{4,
author={Author Four},
title={Title Four},
publisher={Publisher Four},
}

@book{256,
author={Author TwoFiveSix},
title={Title TwoFiveSix},
publisher={Publisher TwoFiveSix},
}

@book{10000,
author={Author TenThousand},
title={Title TenThousand},
publisher={Publisher TenThousand},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sorting=sortbyentrykey]{biblatex}

%i have 3 bib files located in the same folder as this file
\addbibresource{numbered.bib}

%i defined a sorting template that will sort according to entry key
\DeclareSortingTemplate{sortbyentrykey}{\sort{\field[padside=left,padwidth=9]{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{4}
\nocite{10000}
\nocite{256}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



thank you, Ulrike Fischer . I can sense with probability 0.999999999 that your answer is very useful, and correct.

hi @Ulrike Fisher, i just tested your solution. it works! thank you ;) i have more than 25000 references. i now have the option to sort them numerically ;)
